# dynamically loading javascript fails, but innerHTML does

Tags: javascript, php, html

i've wrote a script in which javascript file and innerHTML refreshes time to time

```
setInterval(activeload,1000);

function activeload() {

    activediv.innerHTML="";
    scriptsrc.src="http://localhost/mypro/pro/activeuser.php";
    for(i=0;i<=activeuser.length;i++) {
        if(activeuser[i]!=null)
            activediv.innerHTML+="<p onclick='dial(' " + activeuser[i] +" ' )'> " + activeuser[i] +"</p><br>";
    }

    scriptsrc.src='';   
}
```

in the above script, innerHTML is modifying, but **src** attribute of script is not changing...
the js file loaded is

```
<script src="http://localhost/mypro/pro/activeuser.php" id="scriptsrc" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

this **php** file refreshes every 5 secs and is accurate in information.

need some help in loading the javascript perfectly

Comment: What is the value of `scriptsrc`? More importantly, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: `var scriptsrc=document.querySelector('#id_of_script_tag');`

Comment: im trying to represent some live data to user...so im using `setInterval` for frequent updating of information

Comment: Why do you want to change the script source to accomplish that?

Comment: as the script `src` is `php` which gives updated array at every interval of time. Im not actually changing script src, but reloading the same script again, please help

Comment: Do you know about AJAX?

Comment: thanks understanding my problem! i referred to `ajax` scripts before asking this questions, but i didnt understood because of their complexity. please offer me simpler form for perfect INTRANET connectivity using android-crosswalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not clear to me what you want to do with the array that comes from `activeuser.php`, it seems like AJAX will be your best bet to bring it in to your page on a regular interval. Here is a basic example of an AJAX call using jQuery:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax("/mypro/pro/activeuser.php").done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

}, 5000);

</script>
```

The way it works is that the `$.ajax()` call will request `activeuser.php` from the server. As soon as the file is delivered, the anonymous function inside of `.done()` will be called. That function has one parameter, which I've named `data`, that contains the contents of `activeuser.php`.

AJAX is a very convenient way to request data from the server without reloading the entire current page when the data is delivered to the browser.

Comment: thank you so much,but i got an plain text in result `["user2","user1","user3"]`. how to convert this as an array?